# Display list of data received from PHP on an Ionic page

Tags: php, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have successfully sent an `http.post` request to PHP and retrieved some data from a MySQL database, in the form of an array containing several objects.

I can echo the data into the console.log of my browser.
Also, the auth.service.ts with the `http.post` receives the date and I have it stored in a variable - a console.log confirms this.

However, I do not know how to show this data via the HTML page. I have seen older versions of angular users doing similar on youtube etc, but cannot translate what they have done to my project.

I don't know where to start...

```
AUTH.SERVICE.TS (this functions)

getCoursList(date) {
return this.http.post('http://localhost/Attendance App/myApp/src/app/api/getCours.php', {
  date,
}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(Object.values(data));
  const planning = Object.values(data);
  const grabArray = planning[0];
  const id = grabArray.intervenant;
  if (id !== undefined) {
    // console.log('test array', id);
    this.router.navigate(['/cours/', id]);
  };
},

GETCOURS PHP FILE (this functions)

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM planning WHERE intervenant = :id AND date = :date");
$stmt->execute([':id' => $id, ':date' => $date]);

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // $output = array();
    $output = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($output);
} else {
    $errors = "No data found for this date";
    echo json_encode($errors);
}

CONSOLE LOG DISPLAY OF RESULTS


[object Array]: [Object, Object]

0: Object
cours: "CFA"
date: "2019-09-20"
duration: "1h30m"
etudiant: "12"
id_planning: 1
intervenant: "2"
lieux: "Nice 1"
time: "13:15:00"

__proto__: Object

1: Object
cours: "Outils Numeriques"
date: "2019-09-20"
duration: "1h30m"
etudiant: "16"
id_planning: 4
intervenant: "2"
lieux: "Monaco High School"
time: "13:15:00"

__proto__: Object
length: "2"
```

So I would like what is displayed in the console log, to be displayed on an HTML page, produced dynamically upon loading.

This is probably very simple as I already have the data at hand, but this is my first little app project and Ionic makes me dizzy!

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: add your console.log JSON data view

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Use http.get method to get posted data

Comment: @user9088454 But I already have the data from using the http.post on the service.ts. It is stored in a variable. I need to transfer this data into a new html page. Unless you are saying to use http from one ionic page to another? That seems bizarre, but I'm open to any ideas at the minute!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to display your array data like this:

data = your obj of array
in page.ts

```
datalist: any[];

this.datalist = data

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let d of datalist ">
      <p>{{d.cours}}</p>
      <p>{{d.date}}</p>
      <p>{{d.duration}}</p>
      <p>{{d.etudiant}}</p>
      <p>{{d.id_planning}}</p>
      <p>{{d.intervenant}}</p>
      <p>{{d.lieux}}</p>
      <p>{{d.time}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Let me know, it's working or not.

Comment: No, because the problem is still the same.
There is the main service page which has the http request, that gets all the info from PHP.
There is the HTML page where I want to display the info, then there is the page.ts that goes with the html page, but this does not have the http request.
I just tried moving the request there from the service page - BUT, to then link the login page (with the event to start to get the data) to the display page becomes a problem as is it not a service page.
I must be missing something obvious here, it can't be so difficult, but alas I am lost!